# Jetpack Compose Card , getting increased more than the specified width

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, kmm

I made a list in jetpack compose and the items in it are, Like a Card Composable. The basic functionality is to get data from the network and display it. The issue I am facing is that after the initial loading, the cards are displayed ok but when I scroll, after a few items the cards get really big and weird. Though they get back to specified width soon. But is there any way to get rid of this?

Comment: You'll need to share the code to get any meaningful answers.

Comment: Your question is so vague, you need to elaborate more